# In golang, how do I use URLs for image link href and img src in html/template?

Tags: image, function, go, html-templates

I’m trying to use URLs for my href and img src inside my gohtml templates, but I was getting no images (i.e. `<img src="#ZgotmplZ" alt="">`). So I attempted using `template.URL` by implementing a `SafeURL` function, but now I’m basically just getting an empty div for the entire page. The `SafeURL` function is not being accessed. My other function, `IsMultiple`, however, is working correctly. What am I doing wrong with the `SafeURL` function?

```
var funcMap = template.FuncMap{"isMultiple": IsMultiple, "safeURL": SafeURL}

func IsMultiple(index, divisor int) bool {
    return index%divisor == 0
}

func SafeURL(url string) template.URL {
    return template.URL(url)
}
```

```
    pageTemplateMaster := template.New(pageFullName[1])
    _, err := pageTemplateMaster.Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(append([]string{pageFullPath}, layoutsFullPaths...)...)
    if err != nil {
        return pageTemplateMaster, err
    }
```

```
{{ $carModels := index .Data "carModels" }}
{{ range $i, $carModel := $carModels }}
    {{ if (isMultiple $i 2) }}
        <div class="row gv-3 align-items-center mb-100 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 show-on-scroll" data-show-duration="500" data-show-distance="20" data-show-origin="left" data-show-delay="250">
                <a href="{{.ImageHref|safeURL}}" class="gallery-item gallery-item-lg" data-fancybox="gallery-1" data-animation-effect="fade">
                    <img src="{{.ImageSrc|safeURL}}" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="row gv-3 align-items-center mb-100 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-3 show-on-scroll" data-show-duration="500" data-show-distance="20" data-show-origin="right" data-show-delay="250">
                <a href="{{.ImageHref|safeURL}}" class="gallery-item gallery-item-lg" data-fancybox="gallery-1" data-animation-effect="fade">
                    <img src="{{.ImageSrc|safeURL}}" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{end}}
```

Comment: You do not need any special treatment for "inserting" _valid_ URLs. The `html/template` package peforms context-sensitive escaping. If you see `ZgotmplZ` in the output, that means your input was not valid for the context in which you tried to use.

Comment: Thanks @icza for the reply. The issue was that the URLs were of type sql.NullString. So I simply added `.String` to `.ImageHref` and `.ImageSrc`. It works now, even without using the `safeURL` function. Is there a good reason to keep using the `safeURL` function?

Comment: You don't need `safeURL` by default as the template engine does context-sensitive escaping. `safeURL` comes handy when you don't want this automatic escaping.

Comment: @icza   That helps, thanks!